# How can I check whether a variable is an instance of datetime.datetime or datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime

I've tried

```
In [16]: import datetime

In [17]: now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

In [18]: isinstance(now, datetime.date)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: isinstance(now, datetime.datetime)
Out[19]: True
```

What I expected is that the first isinstance should return False. What happened?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `datetime` inherits from `date`, every instance of `datetime` also *is an* instance of `date`, i.e. you can use `datetime` instances wherever you would use `date` instances. This is a [central concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) in object-oriented programming.

To modify the check to do what you want, you can test specifically for `date` by using `type(now) is datetime.date`. Or, you can explicitly exclude `datetime` with `isinstance(now, datetime.date) and not isinstance(now, datetime.datetime)`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use either approach as shown below:**

you can use any random date to compare the date and datetime instance.

**One Way:**

```
a = datetime.date(2021,12,30) 
x = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17) 

print(isinstance(a,type(datetime.date(2021,12,30)))) #True
print(isinstance(a,type(datetime.datetime(2021,12,30)))) #False
```

**second Way**

```
a = datetime.date(2021,12,30)
x = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)

print(isinstance(a, a.__class__)) # True
print(isinstance(a, x.__class__)) # False
```