# what is the quickest way to check for type(datetime.date) python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am getting hassle checking types for datetime.date. I don't know if getting good typechecks is a hassle in python or if there's something I'm missing:

```
In [14]: type(datetime.date)
Out[14]: type

In [15]: type(d)
Out[15]: datetime.date

In [16]: arbitrary = datetime.date(1990, 1, 1)

In [17]: type(arbitrary)
Out[17]: datetime.date
```

I'd like something simpler than needing to make a fake date within `__init__` each time

```
import datetime

class Month(object):

    def __init__(self, dateobj):
        if type(dateobj) == the type of datetime.date:
            we're good
        else:
            raise Exception('Please feed me a dateobj')
```

What is the fastest way to check these types, since the type of the base class normally returns a useless `type`. Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with `isinstance`? You could also do `type(d) == datetime.datetime`, as `type(datetime.datetime) -> type` might have suggested. Note that `type(...) ==` will check for exact matches, while `isinstance` also works for subclasses.

Comment: What's wrong with duck typing, to start with?

Comment: nothin, that's what I was missing. do yall read the standard library or just find stuff as it comes up

Comment: `isinstance` and `type` are not in the standard library, they are [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html). Being familiar with the builtins is a big plus.

Comment: You don't need to get the type of the class, you need the type of the instance, which for instances of normal classes is the class name. i.e. you don't do `if type(dateobj) == the type of datetime.date` you just do `if type(dateobj) is datetime.date`. type() returns the metaclass, and most are constructed using `type()` builtin, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses

Comment: The right answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15654546/1286705 - answers below don't fully distinguish between date and datetime because all datetimes *are* dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
type(your_variable)
```

Or if you know it supposed to be `datetime.date`:

```
isinstance(your_variable, datetime.date)
```

[**`type`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) gives you the type of variable, [**`isinstance`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) returns `True` or `False`.
Example:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today()
>>> type(today)
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>> isinstance(today, datetime.date)
True
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime` is a subclass of `datetime.date` which may or may not be helpful. In that example, `isinstance` would return true for both date and datetime.

Answer (score 7):

I use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance) for type checking:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> isinstance('2016', datetime.datetime)
False
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> isinstance(today, datetime.datetime)
True
```